# Heap doesn't want to change size ( java.lang.OutOfMemoryError) android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, out-of-memory

I am new to android studio and I am developing my first project.

My problem is that every time I try do run apk on mobile phone I get a  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. I tried various ways to fix that but none of that seems to be working.

Here is my console log error report:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.prvaaplikacija.gametutorial, PID: 32565
              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17013900 byte allocation with 13104128 free bytes and 12MB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2952)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2684)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
                  at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:387)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimationDrawable.java:324)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:294)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1217)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1126)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.createFromXml(Resources.java:2964)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2676)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
                  at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:387)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:824)
                  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:467)
                  at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:17225)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatImageView.java:86)
                  at com.example.prvaaplikacija.gametutorial.main.onCreate(main.java:125)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

I created a gradle.properties file in C:\Users\user.gradle and it looks like this:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

My local gradle.properties file looks like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

But when i hoover over it with mouse it gives me me an notice of
[unused property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3f6w.png).

I have added this code to my build.gradle file and tried some variations of options with it, but it still doesn't work.

```
 dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false;
    incremental true 
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

And this:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

I have tried clearing my gradle cache by manually deleting and all of my actions didn't do any change.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with my problem. I am stuck on this for a few days and I think that I alone can't do anything more to solve this.

Comment: It seems you are getting an out of memory in your onCreate(). Can you share the relevant code? (main.java - onCreate())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts at fixing things would fix an `OutOfMemoryError` on your *development machine*. Your crash is coming on the Android device, because your *app* is running out of memory.

Specifically, some drawable resource that you are trying to load — as the background(?) of an `ImageView` — is going to take up 17013900 bytes of heap space, and you do not have a free block of heap space that big.

17013900 bytes is the equivalent of a 2062x2062 pixel image. This is **much too big**.

So:

- Find out what drawable resource this is
- If you put the resource in `res/drawable/`, choose a more appropriate directory (either a density-specific directory like `res/drawable-xhdpi/`, or perhaps `res/drawable-nodpi/` to say that Android should not convert it based on screen density)
- If the resolution of the image is large, make it smaller

Comment: I think I now understand more of my problem. I have created an animated background which consist of 28 frames and they take 743,659 B of space. So should I just make another drawable directory and put hem in?

Comment: @Mithor: I recommend that you read [the documentation on supporting multiple screen sizes and densities](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), then decide how to handle this background.